# C# change dns server

Tags: c#, dns

I want to change the dns server in my C# code.

This is my code: 
The `setDNS()` method does not work and only checked static mode.

The `setDNSDHCP()` method does work, but an unidentified network is added.

So, there are two networks.

```
    public void setDNS(string defaultDNS, string subDNS)
    {
        adapterConfig = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        networkCollection = adapterConfig.GetInstances();
        foreach (ManagementObject adapter in networkCollection)
        {
            if ((bool)adapter["IPEnabled"])
            {
                if (adapter["Caption"].Equals(myDesc))
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject objdns = adapter.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                    if (objdns != null)
                    {
                        string[] s = { defaultDNS, subDNS };
                        objdns["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = s;
                        adapter.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objdns, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setDNSDHCP()
    {
        adapterConfig = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        networkCollection = adapterConfig.GetInstances();
        foreach (ManagementObject adapter in networkCollection)
        {
            if ((bool)adapter["IPEnabled"])
            {
                if (adapter["Caption"].Equals(myDesc))
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject objdns = adapter.GetMethodParameters("EnableDHCP");
                    if (objdns != null)
                    {
                        adapter.InvokeMethod("EnableDHCP", objdns, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's not working.

Please, help me!

I want to use Management!!